# Jquery/Ajax Duplicando

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, bootstrap, servlet

Boa Tarde, pesquisei já este problema aqui no fórum e tentei algumas soluções mas não sei o que posso esta fazendo de errado.

Tenho essa function que chama minha Modal.

```
function verificarSenha() {
                            var forcarAlterarSenha = document.getElementById('forcarAlterarSenha').value;
                            if (forcarAlterarSenha < 1) {
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                                });
                            } else {
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                                });
                            }
                        }
```

Modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="padding: 40px 50px; background-color: #333; text-align: center;">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header" style="background: ${cortop}; color: ${corletra}">
                                        <!--                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>-->
                                        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Senha Expirou</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="senhaAtual"> Senha Atual:</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="senha" onkeyup="javascript:verifica(this);" class="form-control" id="senha" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="novaSenha"> Nova senha:</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="senhan" onkeyup="javascript:verifica(this);" class="form-control" id="senhan" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="confirmaNovaSenha"> Confirmar senha:</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="confirmaNovaSenha" onkeyup="javascript:verifica(this);" class="form-control" id="confirmaNovaSenha" />
                                        </div>  
                                        <strong><div  id="mostra"  ></div></strong><p/>
                                        <input type="button" id="btnabrir" name="btnabrir" value="Alterar" onclick="AlterarSenhaExpirada()" class="btn btn-default" />

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Function que altera a Senha, Passo os dados para minha `Servlet` via `Ajax` .

```
function AlterarSenhaExpirada() {
                            if (document.formLogin.iduser.value > 0) {
                                if (document.formLogin.senha.value.length > 4) {
                                    if (document.formLogin.senhan.value.length > 7) {
                                        if (document.formLogin.senhan.value == document.formLogin.confirmaNovaSenha.value) {
                                            if (document.formLogin.senhaf.value != 'Fraca') {

                                                $('#btnabrir').click(function (event) {
                                                    var t_pagina1 = $('#t_pagina').val();
                                                    var iduser1 = $('#iduser').val();
                                                    var senhaAtual = $('#senha').val();
                                                    var novaSenha = $('#senhan').val();
                                                    var op1 = $('#op').val();

                                                    $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/AjaxAlterarSenha', {t_pagina: t_pagina1, senha: senhaAtual, senhan: novaSenha, op: op1, iduser: iduser1}, function (responseText) {

                                                          if(responseText == 1){

                                                             $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                                                         }
                                                         if(responseText == -2){
                                                               mostra.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 100%" role="alert"> A senha precisa ser diferente da Anterior!</div>';
                                                             $('#myModal').modal('show');
                                                                 }
                                                         if(responseText == -1){
                                                             mostra.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 100%" role="alert">A senha atual não foi confirmada. Não foi possível realizar a alteração!</div>';
                                                             $('#myModal').modal('show');
                                                               }

                                                    });
                                                });
                                            } else
                                                alert('A senha informada é fraca, informe uma senha que contenha letras e numeros!');
                                        } else
                                            alert('A nova senha não foi repetida corretamente!');
                                    } else
                                        alert('A nova senha deve conter ao menos 8 digitos!');
                                } else
                                    alert('A senha antiga não foi informada corretamente!');
                            } else
                                alert('Sua sessão foi encerrada!');
                        }
```

Está funcionando, Porém quando vou apertar no botão `btnabrir` ele não funciona somente quando clico pela 2 vez. E as vezes ele está clicando de 1, porém executa duas vezes, passando pela `servlet`  2 vezes.
O que pode ser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está ocasionando isso. Primeiro você clica no botão e executa a função: `AlterarSenhaExpirada()`, conforme está no `onClick`.

```
<input type="button" id="btnabrir" name="btnabrir" value="Alterar" onclick="AlterarSenhaExpirada()" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Nessa função você declara uma função para o mesmo botão.

```
$('#btnabrir').click(function (event) { }
```

Essa função não é executada da primeira vez. Ela é apenas criada.

Então apenas quando você clicar na segunda vez vai funcionar, porquê ela foi declarada anteriormente.

Você pode colocar essa função de `click` em uma função normal.

```
function executaFuncao(){
    var t_pagina1 = $('#t_pagina').val();
    var iduser1 = $('#iduser').val();
    var senhaAtual = $('#senha').val();
    var novaSenha = $('#senhan').val();
    var op1 = $('#op').val();

    $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/AjaxAlterarSenha', {t_pagina: t_pagina1, senha: senhaAtual, senhan: novaSenha, op: op1, iduser: iduser1}, function (responseText) {
        if(responseText == 1){
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }
        if(responseText == -2){
            mostra.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 100%" role="alert"> A senha precisa ser diferente da Anterior!</div>';
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
        if(responseText == -1){
            mostra.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 100%" role="alert">A senha atual não foi confirmada. Não foi possível realizar a alteração!</div>';
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
}

function AlterarSenhaExpirada() {
    if (document.formLogin.iduser.value > 0) {
        if (document.formLogin.senha.value.length > 4) {
            if (document.formLogin.senhan.value.length > 7) {
                if (document.formLogin.senhan.value == document.formLogin.confirmaNovaSenha.value) {
                    if (document.formLogin.senhaf.value != 'Fraca') {

                        executaFuncao();

                    } else
                    alert('A senha informada é fraca, informe uma senha que contenha letras e numeros!');
                } else
                alert('A nova senha não foi repetida corretamente!');
            } else
            alert('A nova senha deve conter ao menos 8 digitos!');
        } else
        alert('A senha antiga não foi informada corretamente!');
    } else
    alert('Sua sessão foi encerrada!');
}
```

Veja:

Você criou duas funções: Uma pra verificar a senha e a outra para executar quando não parar em nenhuma condição do `if`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado, estou aprendendo a mexer com Ajax agora e fiz uma pequena confusão na function kkkk .

Comment: E se essa tela tivesse 2 botões, eu precisaria criar uma function para o outro?

Comment: Não. Só chamar da mesma maneira pelo onclick.